# IOS swipe for next page with dynamic number of pages

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

How would I implement something like FragmentStatePagerAdapter in android?

```
Question:
- name:String
- description:String
- imageUrl:String?
- option1:String
- option2:String
- option3:String
- option4:String
```

I have a Question class as shown above. For example, if I have an array of 10 Questions, then the user can swipe through the 10 pages with each page populated with the question infos.

There will be also two types of view layout. The imageUrl property will be optional. If the imageUrl != nil, then load the layout that has an imageView.

How would I implement this using the UIPageViewController with two viewControllers that I can keep reusing?

Comment: You can use `UICollectionView`

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

Comment: you might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875261/how-to-build-a-dynamic-uipageviewcontroller)

Comment: create a view for question and repeat in scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement view controller using `UIPageViewController` class or `UIPageControl` and `UIScrollView`.
Or you could use my library [FlexibleViewController](https://github.com/dimpiax/WizardViewController), where is easy set up: using `setViewControllers` or `setView` function there.